# Conditional ?: operator for ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I want to add following code into the following code into Form1_Load function so that if serial port COM port is attached, the combobox will choose it automatically.

But using conditional ?: statement, I can't figure out how to do it.

So if combobox contains more than 1 item, it choose 2nd item of combobox. Otherwise it choose  0th item

`comboBox1.Items.Count > 1 ? comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 : comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's suppose to be `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count > 1 ? 2 : 0`